# What should be the extension for a python program script?

Tags: python, file

I am new to programming and trying to write basic programs in python. It is difficult to type everything in terminal. So, I want to create a text file where i can write codes or make changes, save it and run directly in python. But what is the extension that I have to save this text file inorder to recognize it as a python script?

Comment: The correct extension is `.py`, which would have been easily found by even the most simple google search.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the extension `.py`.

Example `test.py`.

Comment: Not sure why you are being downvoted. This is correct as long as the user has python installed

Comment: At @akkatracker yep maybe someone just doesn't like people actually answering such simple questions or questions that are almost certainly duplicates. I'd suggest they use their close vote or else flag the question if they find the question itself to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Python cannot run code asynchronously, based on changes (not in Linux nor in Windows), you will always need to rerun the script after you made some changes.

The straight answer is, save as .py. This is how your OS will know which type of file it is and will, in some cases, process it accordingly (Windows will, for example, try to open it with Python, directly.).

> -> python script.py
>   -> made some changes and hit save.
>   -> python script.py

^ This is the only possible flow.

I recommend using a text editor such as Notepad++ which will highlight the syntax for you, to make the code more readable and which will automatically save the file as '.py' based on the syntax you chose.

Please use google / the search function next.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will save your files with the '.py' extension

Then for instance you would type into your terminal: 'python path/to/your/file.py'

and it will execute the code

If you want your file to be executable - ie you write some code in a text file and save it as 'somefile.py' and you want to be able to double click it to automatically run the code then you can add the path to your python command at the beginning of the file after a hashbang:

'#! path/to/my/python/command'

' your code here'

'import blah as blah'

'do something'

then save that file as 'somefile.py'

make the file executable using a chmod command like 'chmod +x somefile.py'

then you should be able to double click the file to automatically open it and execute the code